# Sqoop can I change schema from Mysql to HBase

Tags: sqoop

Let's say I have a mysql table called "users", it has columns like 
`user_name, user_id, user_address, user_level`.

Can I use sqoop to import the data into HBase with some columns renamed and dropped? e.g. they my columns might look like this when they are imported to HBase:

rowkey: `user_id`

columns: `u_name, user_address`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. To change column names you can use free query and use statements such as "Select [insert column] as".

Statement would look like this:

```
sudo sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://[host ip]/databasename --username [your username] --password [your password] --hbase-table [your hbase table] --column-family cf --hbase-row-key user_id --query "SELECT user_id, user_name AS u_name, user_address AS u_address FROM users WHERE \$CONDITIONS -m 1"
```

Note: Your query must include the token $CONDITIONS which each Sqoop process will replace with a unique condition expression. You must also select a splitting column with --split-by or use "-m 1".

And you can ignore the other columns in the select statement. Please note though, that you may want to put more in your row-key besides just the id as this is where HBase is powerful in retrieving records and consider adding md5 to avoid region hot spotting. You can do this with MySQL's "md5" command eg. "md5(user_id) AS md5" and put that before the actual row-key to get a nice distribution of keys across region servers.